# Why side menu swipe not working in ionic3?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I recently build ionic app(Ionic 3).But the side menu swipe is not working in android phone.It works fine in ionic serve --lab in chrome.

Menu only opens when i click menu button in android phone.I checked whether it's my code problem,turns out it's not.The same problem is present in ionic beginner side menu template.Is there something i'm missing?Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the `code`?

Comment: The problem is there even for ionic 3 starter side menu. So you can look up that code,i guess.

Comment: Even ran the same app in latest emulator.Still no swipe.